# Wordpress site periodically goes down

Tags: plugins, themes, errors, bug

my site https://mediatrends.me/ periodically goes down. It works fine and then all of a sudden any page becomes unreachable in every web browser. "site can't be reached", etc. After a few minutes it goes back to normal and works okay again before randomly cutting out again.

Edit: Site literally cuts out and becomes inaccessible every few minutes.

Edit two: the exact error is "mediatrends.me refused to connect." on chrome and "Unable to connect" on firefox.

Comment: Does it say why?  Timeout etc? : Talk to your host.  Is it only in chrome? https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sv0YttC20cU.  Do a little experimenting and debugging and provide as much info as you can.

Comment: I'm running it on digitalocean. I have networking and webserver experience myself but I wanted to build a project on top of wordpress. It says its not available in firefox and can't be reached in chrome. Will update with exact text next time it happens. Not sure what things I can actually debug to test this.

Comment: Assuming you've looked at the error.log file (in root and in wp-admin)? Can you enable debugging to error.log file, but not to screen?  (I suspect that you've already done this, considering your apparent experience, but mention it for any lurkers.) Also, if you know date/time things are happening, perhaps a look at the access logs to see what requests are doing around that time.

Comment: Theres literally nothing in the error log about it, nor in the access log

Comment: GIven that it's intermittent, it sounds performance related.  This post has some info on 'connection refused' where there is a backlog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333400/what-can-be-the-reasons-of-connection-refused-errors